# How to disable the function of the up button?

Tags: android

public class StaffMainMenu extends ActionBarActivity{

```
Button staffinfo,fulfillservice,shipmentlist,trackparcel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_staff_main_menu);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //setupActionBar();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    staffinfo = (Button) findViewById (R.id.staffinfo);
    fulfillservice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fulfillservice);
    shipmentlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shipmentlist);
    trackparcel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stafftrackbutton);

    staffinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(StaffMainMenu.this, StaffInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    fulfillservice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(StaffMainMenu.this, FulfillRequest.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    shipmentlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(StaffMainMenu.this, ShipmentList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    trackparcel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(StaffMainMenu.this, StaffTrackParcel.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(StaffMainMenu.this).setTitle("Logout")
    .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(StaffMainMenu.this, Login.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(StaffMainMenu.this);
            Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.commit();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // user doesn't want to logout
        }
     })
    .show();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.staff_main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;

    case R.id.action_logout: {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(StaffMainMenu.this)
                .setTitle("Logout")
                .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(StaffMainMenu.this,
                                        Login.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(StaffMainMenu.this);
                                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                                edit.clear();
                                edit.commit();
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // user doesn't want to logout
                            }
                        }).show();
    }
        return true;    
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

I want to disable the up button on the actionbar. Since I already declare this 2 lines
`ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` and `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` It does have effect on my user main menu BUT it doesn't have effect on my staff main menu.. Or I have done something wrong about the code? Please tell me if it is...

Comment: I don't understand clearly the difference between "*my user main menu*" and "*my staff main menu*", what do you mean here?

Comment: "I want to disable the up button" - does this mean you don't want it to show up on the actionbar, or that you don't want it to do anything when clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

The `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` method doesn't affect the UI because of this line:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

With this method above, you inform the system that this `Activity` has [a `Parent Activity`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent) and, in fact, **this automatically shows and handles the Up indicator**.

If you want to disable the `Up`, you must remove these lines from the `Manifest` file:

```
android:parentActivityName="com.package.name.ParentActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.package.name.ParentActivity" />
```

in your `<activity>` tags. This will prevent the `Up` indicator to be shown and handled.

Since you declare this `Parent/Child` design, I don't think you can disable the `Up`. *(I might be wrong but I think you cannot do this programmatically here)* This method from [`NavUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html) class implements recommended Android UI navigation patterns. Then, I don't see how you can override the `Up` with it.

A workaround can be interesting for your purpose. Indeed, if you want to keep the [`navigateUpFromSameTask()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpFromSameTask%28android.app.Activity%29) method and a `Parent/Child` design, but without the `Up` drawable, maybe you can try to prevent it from the style:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
```

With this, the `Up` drawable will not be shown. And then for other Activities, if you need to show it, you have to set a custom icon with an `Up` indicator at its left.
Or even try to disable this drawable dynamically with [`setHomeAsUpIndicator()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) as follows:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.empty);
```

Where `empty` drawable, it's just a transparent png. Set it to `null` seems to be the same behaviour than `0`: "*the default drawable from the theme will be used*", so it does not work.